# Alternative for file access in windows share files

Tags: linux, windows

We have an application (built on .NET), which will need to read some  mass storage files.

So we deploy the application in the Web server, and put the data in the data server. Then the application in the web server will access the files through windows share files.(Both the Web server and data Server use the Windows Server OS.

Now, we tried to change from windows to linux, then how about the file access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Samba](http://www.samba.org/) suite provides windows file server functionality for unix systems.

Also you might like to look at [NFS](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/).

Even [OCFS2](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/) might be an alternative.

Comment: BTW, how about we change both the web server and data server to linux?

Comment: @hguser: In general a good idea, but would the `.NET` code still run?

Comment: Of course not, we plan to rewrite the application in java. I mean if the `Samba` still the choice in this case.